# How do you use regex flags in postfix?

Tags: postfix, regex

In Postfix we can apply some basic header, body, client checks using regex. I wanted to use flags.

I added the following to the header_checks file:

`/some(\s|_|-)words(\s|_|-)here/gmi REJECT`

and tested it by sending myself and email with those words in the title, but I get the error in my maillog stating `unknown regexp option "g": skipping this rule`

Is there a proper way to apply flags or does postfix regex simply not use or acknowlege certain flags?

Comment: If you meant to `REPLACE` instead of `REJECT`, it is still not possible, because header_checks stops searching after the first match is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no supported flag `g`, neither in [POSIX regexp tables](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html) or [PCRE tables](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html). Therefore it's impossible to understand what you intended. Is that a typo? Just remove it.

Comment: Thank you. I had copied it from another case I had done in a script. The only flag I really wanted was `i` but after reading the link you just shared, I learned that these in postfix the regex is case insensitive by default.